# Professional Scanner with nmap

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners, scan

Can one scan a range of IP addresses and detect if a specific version of FTP-, which is FTP Service 7.5 is running using `nmap`?

Comment: Your problem is probably more a lack of details than a language issue as the first line is perfectly understandable but missing so much information to make it answerable.  What do you mean about the `FTP service uses X version`?  Are you looking to extract that with `nmap` or provide `nmap` a list of IP addresses?

Comment: Thank you for your response .                                                                             

I want to scan a range of IP Version 7.5 is that the FTP service.                                     

I hope I got it right

Comment: nmap -sV is the flag which detects service versions. You can find more details at https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html

Comment: `nmap` doesn't know what service is actually listening on the remote port.  There is no way of knowing the FTP server's version remotely either.  Note that there are quite a few different FTP servers out there so just having a version number is quite imprecise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:
`nmap -sVV -pT:21,2121,21212 -oG - iprange| grep - bannerstring`, and adjust parallel min and max values to suit your needs. you probably want to log the session, use `script nmap.log`.
what you want has already been done better -> https://www.shodan.io/
enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes, you can use nmap to detect what is listening on a specific port, using

```
nmap -sV
```

This works well when the service provides a descriptive banner, but some services do not, and nmap is unlikely to be able to differentiate.

As there are many FTP servers from different vendors, you'd need to be much more specific about what you are searching for. Version 7.5 of what?

Comment: tanx  , The command you said, between hundreds of IP versions to be found?